# .jar doesnt run on debian

Tags: java, class, classpath, program-entry-point

Im trying to execute a .jar file i have like 3 days trying to run it and nothing i tried right clink and run with java and nothing happens, i tried like a million ways in the console but nothing, the programs runs fine on NetBeans but when i compile i get nothing i checked the manifest and its ok and when i run with the console i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dist/ModuloControlAcceso
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dist.ModuloControlAcceso
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: dist.ModuloControlAcceso.  Program will exit.
```

The path of my project is /home/user/NetBeansProjects/ModuloControlAcceso/dist

The manifest is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.6.0_26-b03 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Class-Path: /home/victor/NetBeansProjects/ModuloControlAcceso/dist/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: modulocontrolacceso.ModuloControlAcceso
```

Im sorry im a noob in java this is my first program and my english isn't good either so i would apreciatte a full explanation to solve my problem.

Comment: There seems to be a disconnect between the complaint `dist.ModuloControlAcceso` and the Main-Class: `modulocontrolacceso.ModuloControlAcceso`.  I believe these should be the same.  What is your command line when you try to run?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using eclipse then first clean all files using following steps

```
   project->clean->select clean all -> and then click on
```

after that right click on your project

```
   Export->click on Runnable jar->click next next and then finish
```

Problem will be solve.

Comment: Okay i found a solution i was focusing only in the classpath errors, but there was nothing wrong with that i just choose the wrong "main" before compiling, thanks for the quick answer...

Comment: please don't forget to like and click on correct answer if the answer is helpfull